# Bundle product add to cart issue : Call to a member function getPosition() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, bundled-product

I am facing very weird issue on my server while adding bundle product in the shopping cart.Whenever I am trying to add my bundle product, it gives me error like

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getPosition() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Type.php on line 850.`

While debugging in this file ,just find that **first** `magento` set it bundle product option and then find its `position` value .

`magento` set it option from this line

```
        $optionsCollection->appendSelections($selections, false, $_appendAllSelections);
```

from this method.

```
protected function _prepareProduct(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode)
```

But `magento` didn't set it option[Not sure why this occur] and try to get `Position .

Can any one help me to sort out this weired issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad.

It create an issue due to 3rd party extension. After disabling the that extension its working fine.

Comment: I think I may be running into the same issue. Might you remember which extension you disabled?

Answer (score 1):

A few years late, but here is some info:

Have a look at this function:

`Mage_Bundle_Model_Resource_Option_Collection::appendSelections`

[image]

Notice the internal flag: $this->_selectionsAppended

If, this routine was called, at any point prior to your add to cart functionality, the line items will not get the product option appended to the product options, which then will result in the given error.

The noted routine is called from here:

`Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type::_prepareProduct`

and if that flag was set, no options tagged to object, error.

In the accepted answer the module that gt disabled is most likely making a call to this routine, causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you, was my problem !

Answer (score 0):

Some time it happened for the wrong bundle_option selection id.so please check that array if you are adding bundle product using your own code.